# Predicting male and female incidence rates over time

Tags: regression

I have time series data for any number of time points for both males and females. Would it make sense to have sex as the entity in the panel approach?

I have data on the annual rates at which a particular disease occurs. I also have the spending that has been allocated each year for screening for this disease. Obviously, spending is not stratified by sex. I wish to treat spending as the IV and incidence as my DV.

```
Year  Sex  Incidence     Spending
1998  F    20.1  300.2
1998  M    30.3  300.2
1999  F    21.4  350.9
1999  M    31.5  350.9
2000  F    20.8  329.7
2000  M    32.1  329.7
...
```

Comment: Just to understand your data. You don't have raw data? You just have average levels of your dependent variable for males and females, and this variable has been measured at multiple time points for both groups? You may want to give a little more detail.

Comment: Just added some example data

Comment: But what data have you got?  Do you have data on individuals? Are there multiple people for each sex and year? Are they the same people year after year?  Please see my blog post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) for some guidance on getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data and analysis is all at the aggregate level (i.e., gender means for incidence and population means for spending). Therefore, it seems like you have a more traditional time series with a time-varying covariate (i.e., spending). And thus, you don't have panel data in the normal sense of multiple people each measured on multiple occasions.

Your exact analysis options depend somewhat on how many time points you have. If you have lots of time points, you can estimate more sophisticated models of time.

You could start by (a) graphing the data, and (b) running a basic regression model predicting incidence, from sex, spending, the sex by spending interaction, year and perhaps year-squared.

That said, if you only have a small number of time points (e.g., 5 to 10), you may want to keep the model even simpler.

Also, with spending, you'd know doubt want to think about issues like adjusting for inflation and so on.